# connecting local host with lambda to access dynamodb

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, localhost, aws-api-gateway

How can i connecting my local host with Visual studio to lambda function to access dynamodb with API gateway and in python language. **I don't want to use SAM.** Just a simple lambda function to GET a value from dynamodb and that function must be triggered from local host in PYTHON language.
Kindly help.

Comment: Hey Arun, perhaps you can try rewording your question or give us a sample of the code you have already tried. Unfortunately its not very clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: my task is to connect my localhost to invoke a lambda function, which triggers an API in order to access a dynamodb table. So, i'm using visual studio software to write a code for local host end with get method.

Comment: What is your _specific_ problem? Are you able to invoke the Lambda function? Are you able to write the Lambda function access DynamoDB? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: I have set an api trigger in lambda function. When i run the lambda function, i was able to get the data from dynamodb. But when i use the api link or click the api link, i'm redirected to a web page, where i should get an event generated by the api. But i'm getting "{"message": "Internal server error"}" this message.

Comment: MY lambda code is:import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("THIS IS EVENT",event)
    empid = event["queryStringParameters"]["employeeId"]
    print(empid)
    # print(event)
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table("arun_employee_demo")
    
    response = table.get_item(
        Key = {"emp_id": empid})
    print(response)if("Item" in response):
        return json.dumps(response['Item'])
    else:
        return ("NO DATA FOUND")

Comment: Please place your code and the traceback from the error message which you can get from Cloudwatch in your question so that it can be markdown formatted so we can read the code.